# How to log custom ado.net SQL queries in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I use EF Core and ADO.NET for custom SQLs.
I get all EF Core SQLs in my log files, but I do not see my custom SQLs (created using DbCommand).

How to log **ALL** SQLs my .net core app sends to the database?

Comment: _"custom SQLs (created using DbCommand)"_ - why? Just use `context.Query<T>.FromSql("Query")`?

Comment: Well one good reason to use ADO.NET in conjunction with EF is of course to optimize SQL queries beyond what EF is capable of. EF does have a significant overhead cost, even when only executing `.FromSql("Query")`. However that overhead does include logging capability.  ADO.NET does not have logging, you'll have to write that yourself.

Comment: Can you update the post with your configurations and a custom sql call? To understand better your problem

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET does not have logging (thank you @adam-vincent).

When performance is not an issue, [Query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) may be created as described in [Raw SQL Query without DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core) and [Entity framework Core Raw SQLQueries with custom model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278258/entity-framework-core-raw-sqlqueries-with-custom-model)
 for `context.Query<T>.FromSql("Query")`.

Trying to query a type that is not registered as a 'query type' results in an error "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ReportStatusCount' because this type is not included in the model for the context.".

Query types must have properties not fields.